Generate set of numbers containing 3 consecutive 1, but without the elements of the previous set
So I have this specific problem that I couldn't figure out. I want to create a set $F_n$ containing all bitstrings that has 3 consecutive 1s, but not those that are already contained in all the previous sets when we consider the last $n-1$ bits. For example, at n=3:
$$F_3 = \{ 111 \}$$.
At $n = 4, F_4 = \{0111,1110,1111\}$. However, if we consider the last 3 bits, $0111$ and $1111$ are already accounted in the previous set. Therefore,
$$F_4 = \{ 1110 \}$$.
Consequentially, $F_5 = \{00111, 01110, 01111, 10111, 11100, 11101, 11110, 11111 \}$, but subtract from $F_3$ and $F_4$ and we have
$$F_5 = \{ 11100, 11101 \} \\ 
F_6 = \{111000, 111001, 111010, 111011 \} \\
F_7 = \{1110000, 1110001, 1110010, 1110011, 1110100,
       1110101, 1110110 \}$$.
I suppose I can create these sets using an algorithm, but I wonder if there's a mathematical pattern in this procedure? Maybe somebody would be familiar with a bitshift trick that help me generate $F_n$ very quickly? Please tell me what you think. Thank you!

So...you want the strings that begin $1110$ followed by some binary string that does not contain $111$, right?  Easy to count those, (and easy to produce them recursively).

I realized you're right, and that does simplify the problem. But I'm thinking as to how to produce them as efficiently as possible.

Recursive methods are very efficient.  Even counting them...I don't know a good non-recursive way to do it.  The  "tribonacci" recursion, $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ hasn't got a useful closed form solution.  See A000073

You don't  count $11111$ in your examples, but the last four bits are $1111$ which has not appeared before (in a kept string). Is that your intent?

@paw88789 I believe they mean that the last $k$ bits of a string in $F_n$ cannot belong to $F_{k}$, for all $3 \le k \le n-1$. That way $11111$ is excluded from $F_5$ due to $F_3$ containing $111$.

Given a binary string $b$ of length $n$, let $\bar{b}$ denote the binary string of length $n-4$ obtained by removing the first $4$ leading digits of $b$ (which must be $1110$ if $b \in F_n$). Then, $b \in F_n$ if and only if $\bar{b}$ does not contain the string $111$. Ex: $F_7$ will be determined by all strings of length $3$ which do not contain $111$, i.e. ${000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110}$. Now just add $1110$ to the beginning of each of these strings, and you obtain $F_7$.

@KimDong Any $\Theta(2^n)$ time algorithm would be optimal as the number of strings in $F_n$ is $\Theta(2^n)$. If you are interested only in the size of $F_n$, then that can be calculated in as little as $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ time with matrix expo

The numbers included in set $F_n$ must start with $111$ and the next $n-3$ digits must have no consecutive string of $111$ otherwise it would have been included earlier. We can further deduce that every string in $F_n$ must start with $1110$ and then have no substring of three 1s afterward. If you want to generate it with a program for every following digit you can split off into two branches 1 or 0 but after you've had two 1s in a row you must have a 0. A python program is attached below.

Sorry if this is not as efficient as you want. I think you can optimize heavily by saving the old generated strings and just adding with dp but I'm not that good at programming.
